# BOX2Dでbodyを拡大縮小することはできますか？

Tags: cocos2d-x

cocos2d-x 3.１を使ってiPhoneアプリを作っています。
Box2Dで作ったbody、それに紐付いた画像を両方同時に拡大縮小をすることは可能ですか？

よろしくお願いします。